# Draw Image in UIView Xamarin.IOS C#

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have some pdf images in Asset catalog. Instead of directly using this in UIImageView, I want to draw this in my UIView using CGContext.

Similar to **Android.Graphic.Drawable - OnDraw()**

Is there an alternatives for this in IOS?
Or is there any samples that i can refer to?

I also want to set the position of this image - similar to **OnMeasure(int width, int height)** in Android.View

(need - I want to dynamically draw images and edit the images on touch positions in UIView)

Could someone guide on this please.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your UIView subclass's Draw (`drawRect:`) override, you can draw on the current context. In this example, we paint the entire view red and then draw and scale a `CGImage` from the center of the view with a size of 100x200:

```
public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
{
    var context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();

    context.SetFillColor(UIColor.Red.CGColor);
    context.FillRect(rect);

    var cgImage = UIImage.FromFile("face").CGImage;

    var drawImageToRect = new CGRect(rect.Width / 2, rect.Height / 2, 100, 200);
    context.DrawImage(drawImageToRect, cgImage);
}
```

Re: [iOS Drawing Concepts](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html)

If you need to mix UIKit and CoreGraphics origins, you can transform the origin (consult the `Coordinate Systems and Drawing in iOS` in the Apple doc link above):

```
public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
{
    var context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
    context.SaveState();
    context.TranslateCTM(0, rect.Height );
    context.ScaleCTM(1, -1);

    context.SetFillColor(UIColor.Red.CGColor);
    context.FillRect(rect);

    var cgImage = UIImage.FromFile("face").CGImage;
    var drawImageToRect = new CGRect(rect.Width / 2, rect.Height / 2, 100, -200);
    context.DrawImage(drawImageToRect, cgImage);

    context.RestoreState();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I tried using the above, but my image appears upside down. And my image is in stretch mode. is there a way to set the scale to Aspect fit?

Comment: In terms of scale/aspect ratio, use the size of the original image to calculate the size the rect use in the `context.DrawImage` method, as far as upside down, yes it would be if you are using **upper left** as 0,0 that is for UIKit functions, using CoreGraghics, 0,0 is at the **bottom left**: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Art/flipped_coordinates-2_2x.png I updated my answer....

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked for me.
However, I am doing some calculations based on my CGRect. Is there any other override method which would be called before onDraw(), so that i need not do the calculations on each time I call onDraw.

Comment: Any override methods available to call before calling Draw method?

Comment: @Praddy There are a number of overrides available depending upon what you are looking for, setFrame: setBounds:, the constructors, etc.. It depends upon when you can perform your calculations and what results you can "cache" without needing the rect that needs drawn. Read the discussion section of `drawRect:`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622529-draw

Comment: Hi Sushi, In the constructor or setFrame, I always get the size as Width:0 an Height:0, where in Draw(CGRect rect), my rect size is Width:375 Height:545. why is this? am i missing something here? or do i need to look otherwise?

Comment: @Praddy The size can not be determined until the view gets laid out in some fashion, so if you are using the constructor that includes a `CGRect` then you have the *requested* rect size, otherwise yes the size would be 0,0 at first. Frame/Bounds can also be programmatically set, if you are using auto-constrants then the frame/bounds will be called, etc... the Apple docs do a decent job of describing how UIViews work (they are the core foundation of all drawing in UIKit....)